# htaccess redirection for download.php?fid=##

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

Is there a way to redirect this : 
`http://example.com/download.php?fid=##`
to another url?

I tried to use Redirect 301 in htaccess but it is not working for me.
Basically, I have an script , where you click on a button and you download a file, that is stored in your website, in your root folder, but I want to store the file externally, for example in Dropbox. If you copy the hyperlink of the button, you get `http://example.com/download.php?fid=##`  --- where `##` is query string that identifies the file.

If I remove the `?fid=##` part, it works, but then all the downloads will be redirected  to the same file.

lets say i have 
http://domain.com/download.php?fid=40

I've tried this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=40`
RewriteRule ^sub-dir/download\.php$ /https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/c1x0u1m64i1i186/00431.doc?dl=0/? [L,R=301]`
```

and Ive tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/download.php$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^fid=40$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/c7x0u1m14i1i186/00431.doc?dl=0   [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How is the identifier (`##`) applied to the dropbox URL? Do you intend to hard-code mappings for each `id=` to its respective dropbox URL?  The `RewriteCond/RewriteRule` pair you have now is nearly correct but you have an errant leading `/` at `/https:`

Comment: Yes, I have some ULRs , for example http://domain/download.php?fid=40 or http://domain/download.php?fid=35 , I want to store those files in Dropbox for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the second block of code its working for me now